# Missing NETStandard.Library when create Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard-2.0

When I create a new Xamarin.Forms project I got the yellow triangle telling me that I am missing some packages.

[image]

Here is what I did:

I reinstalled Visual studio 2017 (I am using version 15.8.9).

If I re-open the project, it's just gone. There is no SDK under the Dependencies anymore.

I used Nuget Package Manage console to try to install the missing library, but nothing happened.
[image]

So I would like to hear you guy's opinions. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running the Visual Studio installer and checking the checkbox for xamarin? `Visual Studio Installer -> Workloads -> Mobile development with .Net`

Comment: I did that for quit a few times already.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out the solution. I updated my windows 10 to the newest version and the problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Came across this issue.
Created a new xamarin forms project using netstandard and got broken references.

Updating all packages in nuget solved the issue.

First build after updating package can take a little bit if xamarin decides that it needs to update its packages.